# import text files to r

Tags: java, javascript, r

I'm trying to import multiple text files to R but I'm not able to
I have the text files stored in a temp file.
They are named as 1.txt, 2.txt up to 32912.txt

I need to find frequent patterns in them

Does anyone know how to import all of them once to R

Comment: Your question seems to be very general. There is a large variety of paths you can take to achieve your goal; Provide a reproducible example or at least pieces of code you used can help users to help you. As a start I advise you with two things: 1) `list.files()` functions and 2) a loop to read files in that objects. But as I've just said there is a huge variety of possibilities.

Comment: I extracted those text files from a column in an excel file using visual basics (corpora)

Answer (score 1):

Substituting in your own path, of course, this will do it:

```
library(quanteda)
mycorpus <- corpus(textfile("~/myDirectoryOfTextFiles/*.txt"))
```

Get the texts out using

```
texts(mycorpus)
```

or read the package instructions/vignette to see further possibilities.